# How to convert two lists into array coordinates in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

In Python, how do I build an array of coordinates given 2 lists of axes, such that the output array contains all the possible coordinate pairs?

e.g.

```
ax1=[1,3,4]
ax2=[a,b]

"""
Code that combines them
"""

Combined_ax1 = [1,3,4,1,3,4,1,3,4]
Combined_ax2 = [a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c]
```

I need this so I can feed combined_ax1 and combined_ax2 into a function without using multiple for loops.

Comment: Use `itertools.product`

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python

Comment: `Combined_ax2, Combined_ax1 = zip(*itertools.product(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 3, 4]))` gets you `(1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4)` and `('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c')`

Comment: Where did `c` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code would get what you require

```
import itertools

ax1=[1,3,4]
ax2=['a','b']

Combined_ax1, Combined_ax2 = zip(*itertools.product(ax1, ax2))
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by using a list comprehension as follows:

```
cartesian_product = [(x, y) for x in ax1 for y in ax2]
```

This code sample will return a list of tuples containing all possible pairs of coordinates.